# Android ListView Select a row through java

Tags: android

i have a listview ,and am write custom selector for the listview, my question is it possible to select a row through java without scrolling the row to top.

Comment: What do you mean a custom selector? Your question is brief, I also am not clear on what you mean by "select a row"; do you want to programatically call the code that would have been called when the user touches or clicks a row?

Comment: I have use the setSelection(position),but the the corresponding row moves to top, i don't want to move the row to top

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope it is useful for you..

```
ListView.setSelection(position);
```

if you want to move at top then

```
 position = 0;
```

Comment: this will move the row to top

Comment: this will move the row to top

Comment: You can add any value instead of "0", whatever you want.. like if you want select second row then position=1; if third row then position=2...etc

Comment: i understand ,but that row move to the top of the screen,that is my problem ,i don't want to move to top

Comment: i explain my requirement completely: i have one activity that contain the listview ,when user scrolls the listview and select an item through trackball,i have started new activity,and kill the previous activity,when user press back button  ,i need to show the listview in same style,ie the item should be selected and maintain scroll position, am able to maintain the scroll position,but when am trying to select trhough setSelection (),the row move to top

Comment: if you want come back to previous activity so why are you kill it..?

Comment: try setOnScrollListener for listview and you will get total visibleitem, first visible item in "onScroll" method. u need to manage your position, first visible item...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.getListView().setSelection(position);
```

Comment: this will move the row to top

Comment: i guess that is what you want : "my question is it possible to select a row through java without scrolling the row to top."